# What to use in Word to allow receiving part to sign the document once exported to PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

In Microsoft Word, it is possible to create text form area, check boxes area and image form area that are editable once exported to PDF, but the signing function available in `Insert > Texte > Add signature` line is exported as an image and is not clickable in the resulting PDF.

Which solution could I use to workaround this ?
Did I miss a Word function to get this working properly ?

Answer (score 1):

No, forms in Word do not remain forms once exported/printed to PDF. You must use a PDF editing application which supports creating PDF forms in order to add form fields to a PDF.

Comment: And Word forms do not allow editing the signature line. Great work Microsoft.

Comment: What do you mean by editing the signature line? A signature field can be placed in a Word form, and signatures can be inserted in that field. If you're using a secure form, that field is then locked, as it should be: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-a-signature-f3b3f74c-2355-4d53-be89-ae9c50022730

Comment: Signature line is locked once the document is set to protected form mode, person filling the form cannot insert certificat signature by clicking on the big X like it does when not protected.

Comment: Protected forms require defining the fields and portions of the form that can accept input and the sorts of input that can be applied to them. Online I found suggestions of using Section Breaks to allow physically signing if using a digitizer or pen.